# Add element to multiple parent nodes at a specific position in xml file

Tags: c#

I need to add a new element "Location" to every parent node "Emp" after the element "ID".

```
<Record>
 <Emp>
  <ID>12</ID>
  <Name>ABC</Name>
 </Emp>
 <Emp>
  <ID>12</ID>
  <Name>ABC</Name>
 </Emp>
</Record>
```

I followed example and the steps in below answer by Erik Philips

[Add an XML node to multiple parent nodes(which have same name)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019355/add-an-xml-node-to-multiple-parent-nodeswhich-have-same-name/52494943#52494943)

```
XmlNodeList xNodeList = doc.SelectNodes("/Record/Emp");  
foreach (XmlNode item in xNodeList)  
{  
  XmlElement xNewChild = doc.CreateElement("Location");  
  xNewChild.InnerText = "USA";  
  item.AppendChild(xNewChild);  
}  
doc.Save(path);
```

Instead of this

```
item.AppendChild(xNewChild);
```

i added new statement

```
item.InsertAfter(xNewChild, doc.SelectSingleNode("Emp//ID"));
```

This inserts the new element right after Emp node starts and not after ID.

```
<Record>
 <Emp>
  <Location>USA</Location>
  <ID>12</ID>
  <Name>ABC</Name>
 </Emp>
 <Emp>
  <Location>USA</Location>
  <ID>12</ID>      
  <Name>ABC</Name>
 </Emp>
</Record>
```

Can anyone suggest me where am i going wrong?

Comment: Take a read of [this](http://sscce.org/) and consider adding both example XML and runnable code that demonstrates this problem.

Comment: Thanks @spender. I have edited the question and added more details. I hope it looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XmlDocument` is an old API and has been superceded by `XDocument`, which provides a somewhat more pleasurable experience when dealing with XML.

Using `XDocument` you can:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString); //acquire your XDocument (perhaps by other means)

var targetElements = doc.XPathSelectElements("//Record/Emp/ID");

foreach (var element in targetElements)
{
    var locationElement = new XElement("Location");
    locationElement.Add("USA");
    element.AddAfterSelf(locationElement);
}
```